# thmtools - custom head format inserts space

Tags: thmtools

I am using [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) to create exercise environments.  The format I am looking for is:

- The exercise number, in bold
- a period and space
- If the exercise note is set (with the `name`) key, the note in bold and another space
- the exercise body

The trouble I'm having is that I'm getting some extra horizontal spacing when the note is set.  Also, if there is an empty block of options, more extra space is inserted.  Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notefont=\bfseries,
    headformat={\NUMBER.\if\NOTE\ \else \NOTE\fi},
    headpunct={},
    notebraces={}{},
    numbered=yes
]{exercise}
\declaretheorem[style=exercise]{exercise}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}foo\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[
    ] bar 
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[name=Baz]baz\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Without the `headformat` key set I don't get any of these extra spaces, but them of course it's not the format I want.  So how do I set `headformat` to get what I want without the extra space?

Comment: Add `\show\NOTE` to your `headformat` definition (somewhere) and see what `\NOTE` looks like. It doesn't just contain the note, but is comprised of an `\if`..`\fi`, so your test wouldn't work.

Comment: Good point.  I think I see why I'm getting so much extra space in the second case.  If there is a nonkeyed optional argument it is taken as an argument to the `name` key.  So the second case is functionally equivalent to `name={ }`.  Or something like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\NOTE` doesn't contain just the note text, but it is a more complex macro.

You get what you want with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools,etoolbox}

\declaretheoremstyle[
    headfont=\bfseries,
    notefont=\bfseries,
    headformat={\NUMBER.\NOTEifnotblank},
    headpunct={},
    notebraces={}{},
    numbered=yes
]{exercise}
\declaretheorem[style=exercise]{exercise}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\NOTEifnotblank}{%
  \expandafter\getreal@NOTE\NOTE\@nil
}
\def\getreal@NOTE\if=#1=#2\@nil{\ifblank{#1}{}{\unskip\textnormal{\ }#1}}
%% fix the error if the optional argument is specified but empty
\let\thmt@shortoptarg\@empty
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
foo
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[ ]
bar 
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[]
bar 
\end{exercise}
\begin{exercise}[name=Baz]
baz
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

in the file `thm-amsthm.sty`, the formatting instruction for the `NOTE` doesn't
account for the possibility of an "empty" option, whether that means just
brackets `[]` in which case it crashes with the message

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\ll@exercise ...mtformatoptarg {\thmt@shortoptarg 
                                              }\fi 
l.22 \begin{exercise}[]
```

or with spaces as you have it.

a patch can be applied to get rid of unwanted spaces.  in the definition

```
\def\thmt@setheadstyle#1{%
```

replace the line

```
\def\NOTE{\if=##3=\else\bgroup\thmt@space\the\thm@notefont(##3)\egroup\fi}%
```

with

```
\def\NOTE{\if=##3=\else\bgroup\thmt@space\the\thm@notefont(\ignorespaces##3)\egroup\fi}%
```

the `\ignorespaces` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  I redefined the macro, and it does cut down on the extra space in the second cases, but there is still some there in the second and third cases. I am guessing Werner's comment needs to be incorporated too.